# Capitalise every other letter in String

Tags: java, android

I want to make a small app that you wright a sentence and the app turns every other letter to a capital letter.

For example: `this is a sentence`
Should be: `ThIs Is A SeNtEnCe`

This is my Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText textGiven;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textGiven = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String sentence = "this is a string";
                char[] array = new char[] {};

                array = sentence.toCharArray(); //put the sentence into a character array

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2) {
                    if (array[i] == ' ') { //if the character is blank, move to the next index
                        i++;
                    }
                    array[i] = Character.toUpperCase(array[i]); //capitalize
                }

                sentence = new String(array); //revert array back to String

                ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("String",sentence);
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, sentence, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
       });
    }
}
```

The probelm is that I want the variable textGiven in the place of "this is a string"
But i cant get the variable to work as a string.
How Can I get the variable as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you looking for this function.

```
fun customFormat(input: String): String {

    val charArray = input.toCharArray()
    val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()

    for (index in charArray.indices) {
        if (index % 2 == 0) {
            stringBuilder.append(charArray[index].toUpperCase())
        } else {
            stringBuilder.append(charArray[index].toLowerCase())
        }
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString()
}
```

Comment: Looing? is that related to https://blog.ndepend.com/crap-metric-thing-tells-risk-code/